# No entra en la función

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.7, django-suit

De DJANGO no sé mucho así que es muy posible que esto se debe a un error muy básico.

He creado un nuevo fichero py y he creado una clase, en la cual si entra, pero en la función no entra.

management/commands.py

```
class CalculaCommand(Command):

    def handle(self, *args, fecha: Optional[int]=None, start: Optional[str]=None, **options):
        print("1")
```

supongo que la función la tengo que llamar en alguna parte

Comment: Cual es la estructura de carpeta en la que tiene este archivo? Para que sea reconocido como comando debe seguir la estructua `management/commands` dentro de la aplicacion.

Comment: si, estoy en management/commands.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me funciona, lo que me pasaba es que aunque juraría que lo había probado antes es que tenía un import que llama una clase Command y por ello en este fichero no me dejaba llamar la class Command (poniendo un alias al import lo arregla)